# Which of the following sets are uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Which of the following sets are uncountable?

1. $A= \{ f:\mathbb{N} \to \{1,2\} \}$
2. $B= \{ f: \{1,2\}\to \mathbb{N} \}$
3. $C= \{ f:\mathbb{N} \to \{1,2\} :f(1) \leq f(2) \}$
4. $D= \{ f:\{1,2\}\to \mathbb{N} :f(1) \leq f(2) \}$

Since $A$ has the cardinality $2^{\aleph_0},\quad A$ is.

Since finite product of countable set is countable and subset of a countable set is countable, $B\  \text{and}\ D$  are countable.

Finally,   $C$ can be interpreted as  $C= \{ f:\mathbb{N} \to \{1,2\} :f(2) \neq 1 \}.$

I think $C$ too uncountable but getting stuck on proving this.

Hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: There is an injective map

$$\{ \{3, 4, 5, \cdots \} \to \{1, 2\}\} \to \{\mathbb N \to \{1, 2\} : f(1) \le f(2)\} .$$

Comment: seems pretty, could you please show a concrete example?

Comment: @yazhini Can you see that the left hand side is uncountable?

Comment: Yes, Of course, since $ f: \{3,4,5,\cdots\} \to \mathbb{N} $ by $f(n)=n-2$ is a bijection.

Comment: Do you mean you want an concrete example of such an injection? @yazhini

Comment: yes John Ma, i mean that

Comment: Something like this would work: $(a_3, a_4, a_5, \cdots ) \mapsto (1, 1, a_3, a_4, a_5, \cdots)$. @yazhini